# Etimología de la frase "cuento chino"

Tags: etimología, refranes

Para los que no la conocen, la frase "cuento chino" significa una historia exagerada e increíble.

Hay quienes afirman con toda confianza que tiene su origen en 1847, año en el que los obreros chinos empezaron a llegar en masa a las costas cubanas para trabajar allí. La clase dirigente de Cuba urdía historias manifiestamente falsas con vistas a atraer a esos jornaleros, a quienes vieron como una alternativa menos polémica a la internacionalmente aborrecida esclavitud. Aunque no he podido encontrar ninguna instancia de este término con su significado moderno que sea anterior a aquel año, tampoco puedo comprobar este origen.

Otras fuentes proponen, en cambio, que se remonta a los viajes de Marco Polo y de otros llamados exploradores europeos, quienes iban a las tierras más remotas del subcontinente asiático o que decían haberlo hecho, y que al regresar a su entorno natal contaban todo tipo de historia exagerada y poco creíble sobre la flora, la fauna, y la gente extraordinarias que supuestamente habían encontrado. Eso no parece tan probable, ya que de haberse acuñado en esa época, habría muchos ejemplares en los textos del Siglo de Oro y de los siglos siguientes, lo que no he observado, pero no se puede descontar la posibilidad de que alguien creara el término en un tiempo menos lejano basándose en la absurdidad proverbial de los cuentos de Marco Polo y de sus homólogos de otros países. Me parece raro, no obstante, que hubiera surgido tal frase en el siglo XIX, cuando China ya no era el tema de cuentos fabulosos, sino un país cualquiera, si bien lejano. Desde luego, en 1840 ya había empezado un conflicto armado entre China y la potencia europea de Gran Bretaña, es decir, las guerras del Opio.

También existe la perspectiva de que es simplemente un insulto racial. Según esta opinión, en algún lugar, ya sea Cuba o España, habría existido una percepción de los chinos como mentirosos, la cual habría afirmado que estaban dispuestos a fabular y a exagerar, de ahí el uso moderno de la frase. Desgraciadamente, esto me parece bastante probable dado que, a lo largo de la historia, esta idea se ha aplicado a una amplia gama de etnias, pero tampoco he podido encontrar pruebas de que la frase provenga de semejante estereotipo.

Para resumir, ¿de dónde proviene esta frase? ¿Hay evidencia concreta de que surgiera de una forma u otra?

Comment: The English phrase [*"Chinese whispers"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers#Etymology) has a similarly obscure etymology.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginemos que un amigo nos cuenta una historia maravillosa, asombrosa, pero que nos resulta difícil o imposible de creer.

Si el relato alcanza la categoría de fabulación, definitivamente acabaremos concluyendo que se trata de "**un cuento de la China**" , o ---mas comúnmente--- "**un cuento chino**".

A pesar de que la expresión parece indicar la procedencia del relato (China) en realidad lo que indica es su inverosimilitud, su manifiesta imposibilidad. De ahí que digamos que es una historia tan exagerada (falsa) que la hacemos equivaler a las que el comerciante, viajero y explorador **Marco Polo** (1254-1324) contara en su obra *Il milione* (*El libro de las maravillas*, conocido también como *Los viajes de Marco Polo*).

Para algunos estudiosos e historiadores, Marco Polo no es un autor al que haya de creérsele cuanto contó. Su grado de veracidad está en entredicho, precisamente por las "licencias" que se tomó para relatar sus aventuras por China y Mongolia.

Quien cuenta la historia (el *cuento chino*) crea un argumento base, en el que va engarzando otras piezas, de tal modo que al interlocutor le cuesta creer que pueda ser verdad. Lo cierto es que la intención es el engaño (la **trola**) de modo que es habitual que se revista de mucha fantasía y se adorne en exceso. Por eso, quien la escucha no sucumbe al embuste, y finalmente le interrumpe con un "¡No me vengas con cuentos chinos!".

Es más que probable que la expresión **cuento chino** se haya creado y extendido a partir de la publicación de *Los viajes de Marco Polo*, pues ya en su época se le tachó de exagerado y fabulador (cuentista). De hecho, el libro se conoce también como "**el millón de mentiras**".

El propio autor, en el Prólogo, ya hacía mención expresa a la posibilidad de que sus lectores no le creerían:

> Grandes Príncipes, Emperadores y Reyes, Duques y Marqueses, Condes, Caballeros y Burgueses. Y personas de todas clases que deseáis conocer sobre las diversas razas de la humanidad y sobre todas las diversidades de las variadas regiones del Mundo; tomad este libro y hacedlo leer para vosotros. Pues aquí hallaréis toda clase de maravillas, y las muchas historias de la Gran Armenia, y de Persia, y de la tierra de los tártaros, y de la India, y de muchas otras regiones sobre las que versa nuestro libro, en detalle y en orden sucesivo, según la descripción de micer Marco Polo, un sabio y noble ciudadano de Venecia, tal como las vio con sus propios ojos. Habrá cosas aquí que por cierto no vio, pero que las oyó de labios de hombres de buena reputación y que hablan verdad. Y escribiremos las cosas que vimos tal como las vimos, y las cosas que oímos tal como las oímos, para que ni un ápice de falsedad arruine la veracidad de este libro, y que todo aquel que lo lea o escuche su lectura se convenza de que todo lo que este contiene es verdad.

Answer (score 0):

**Cuestión:** Expresión "Cuento Chino". Origen.

---

**INTRODUCCION**

Al comienzo realicé una explicación mucho más amplia, pero imaginé que era excesiva en su lectura para llevarla aquí; intenté acortarla, y aún así, me pareció bastante extensa. Opté, a mi pesar, en realizar un resumen en el que se omiten las partes intermedias como las declaraciones que sugieren los tres puntos iniciales de búsqueda y que después de su análisis consideré no hallar en ellos el fundamento buscado. También suprimí aquellas distintas, en las que analizan y se da pie, entre otras, a la antigua Literatura China, donde se reconocen las características fantasiosas, imaginativas y a veces arrogantes, en general, de los personajes de las obras clásicas más destacadas e importantes de aquella literatura, y que tampoco cobraron fundamento en el estudio. Así mismo, en el transcurso de esta indagación comprendí que el propio concepto de "chino" como tramposo, trampa, engaño, regateo con ciertas habilidades, es antiguo, saliendo y expandiéndose más allá de nuestras fronteras y adoptado incluso en otros países, ya que, esa abstracción parece ser un malentendido continuado de origen Español, antes aún de que los viajes marítimos pudieran o no corroborar y ahondar después en la pronunciación de esta singularidad, que teóricamente chocaba con los consejos de Confucio y la observancia global de la sabiduría Oriental .

**RECOPILACIÓN DE DOCUMENTACIÓN**

---

*Cuatro novelas clásicas chinas ([Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuatro_novelas_cl%C3%A1sicas_chinas))*

- Romance de los Tres Reinos (1330) de Luo Guanzhong.
- A la orilla del agua (1373?) de Shi Nai'an.
- Viaje al Oeste (1590) atribuido a Wu Cheng'en.
- Sueño en el pabellón rojo (1792) de Cao Xueqin.

---

Por otra parte, busqué entre los diccionarios y literatura Española, encontrando, entre expresiones y dichos, un libro de 1796, ["*Miscelánea instructiva, curiosa y agradable: tomo II*"](https://books.google.es/books?id=2vMsOtkUA_0C&pg=PA390&dq=procedencia%20de%20cuento%20chino&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY17as_s33AhWmQ_EDHcCLDZMQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=procedencia%20de%20cuento%20chino&f=false). En el libro se introduce una historia llamada "El Bienhechor y El Filósofo", con el sugestivo título "CUENTO CHINO" y en donde llama la atención que al principio de la narrativa aparezcan una gran cantidad de personajes poco fiables, aunque en general, sin nada de relevancia que destacar en el seguimiento y búsqueda de esta expresión, salvo el año y el título.

---

En Español, existía una antigua expresión, *¿Somos chinos?*. Pregunta que se dirige á aquél que pretende engañarnos, para manifestarle con ella que no es fácil. Sin embargo, es aquí en mi opinión, donde se comienza a mezclar y confundir el engaño y lo simple, en este caso, el "juego de los chinos", también conocido por otros nombres y en distintas versiones, juego muy popular en distintas épocas, con la simpleza y lo fácil que es engañar a los chinos procedentes de China, como ocurre en la práctica del juego, pues en aquella expresión se aludía a los chinos, como torpes, faltos de conocimientos y fáciles de engañar, cuando la realidad era bien distinta.

Más tarde en 1821, en un libro en español sobre "El Espíritu de las Leyes" de Montesquieu, señala a los Chinos como "los hombres más tramposos de la Tierra".

**NOTA INFORMATIVA**

---

El resumen siguiente, tiene la dificultad de ser "resumen" y los elementos que incorpora por tanto son aspectos que a priori parecen, obviamente, estar fuera de los contextos que fácilmente reconocemos, y por tanto, puede encontrar cierta dificultad para su comprensión actual, aunque intentaré paliarla dentro de lo posible y explicar, con ayuda de algún enlace la comprensión del término, que encierra variaciones internas, propias de una curiosa ambigüedad, a las que hay que estar atentos.

**RESUMEN**

---

**Resumen del análisis**: La expresión "Cuento Chino" proviene de arrastrar durante siglos una confusión, o mal entendido en el lenguaje, utilizando en nuestro propio idioma una misma voz que designa cosas distintas y que lleva al desconocimiento en el mejor de los casos, ya que en español contamos con palabras homófonas como "chino" y "china" o "cuento" y "cuento", que aparte de aludir a los naturales de China, en el primer caso, nos sirve igualmente para referirnos a una piedrecita de pequeño tamaño que se utiliza como suerte de juego, y que a su vez es origen de otras muchas expresiones, y que casualmente, parece no tomarse en cuenta cuando se intentan explicar este tipo de situaciones que llevan a la confusión, quizás porque la voz "china o chino", aunque conocida, no es la utilizada por lo general en toda España para referirse a una piedra de pequeñas dimensiones, pues a veces se entiende y sirve para designar a una simple "roca" (con distintos tamaños) y esto lleve a la falta de claridad.

**VOCES HOMÓFONAS Y LOCUCIONES ESCOGIDAS**

Estas voces homófonas "chino-china", el devenir del mismo verbo "contar cómo narrar", la acepción de "contar" como cómputo, "contar-contar", cuento, "cuento-cuento", junto la mezcla con el mismo "Juego de los chinos" que trata de engañar al contrario, y otras locuciones antiguas que poseen idéntico sonido, "chino, china" como es "Echar china" con el mismo sentido de "Contar Fabas", que también traba, como se verá, su propia confusión, acabaron por expresar la voz "Cuento Chino" como historias fantásticas, fabulosas, sin fundamento, inverosímiles o simplemente, mentiras.

---

La RAE, informa en el número cuatro de las acepciones sobre la voz "Cuento" y  dice;

"4. - m. **Cómputo**. El cuento de los años".

Interesante de interpretar. "El cuento de los años", como si fuera un cómputo, un cálculo para averiguar el resultado de algo, y sin embargo, lo fácil que podría entenderse aquí la palabra "cuento", como una narrativa,  una fábula, en la que los años relatan una propia historia, un propio cuento.

De hecho la palabra "Cuento" procede del Latín; "***Cuento** "computus" ‘cuenta, cálculo’, derivado de computare ‘contar, calcular’. La acepción de ‘narración corta’ surgió de la idea de ‘enumerar’ hechos*".

---

**EXPRESIONES AMBIGUAS Y CLASES DE CHINOS QUE LLEVAN A EQUÍVOCOS**

No obstante, las confusiones derivadas por esas voces homófonas, en muchos casos continúan en nuestros días mal interpretándose en modismos que se han ido adaptado hacia esa nueva configuración y que ahora se enuncian de forma distinta a su intención inicial, como aquel al que se cita, "Engañar como a un Chino", cuando en realidad es "Engañar como a los chinos", "Engañar a los chinos", (Engañar como en el juego de los chinos, en su versión larga), referido al juego de los niños y no a la persona procedente de China. Esto ha generado desde antiguo y genera, multitud de malentendidos, y lo curioso, es que por mucho que se explique el motivo, ya sea por su razonamiento simple o por el propio desconocimiento u olvido de las personas, se tiende a caer una y otra vez sobre el mismo equívoco.

Muchas personas que tropiezan en este error clásico, llegan a ofenderse o molestarse, sin comprender, la razón verdadera de aquel comentario y aun insisten, tratando de rebuscar en su juicio algún tipo de interpretación que arroje una nueva luz, sin embargo, las búsquedas acaban complicando las respuestas con extrañas explicaciones, normalmente, alejadas y erradas de su fundamento y que no puedan aclarar o no saben justificar aquel malentendido que a algunos parece enojar.

Quizás, sea solo que aquel juego de niños hace años que dejó de ser tan popular, y que apenas queda en la memoria conocimiento o recuerdo del mismo, pues recibía nombres distintos, o como se ha indicado, el concepto de "chino-a" como piedrecita, no sea tampoco el habitual utilizado en todos los lugares.

---

**CUENTO CHINO Y CONCEPTOS CRUZADOS**

En este sentido, y en líneas generales, algo parecido ocurrió con la expresión "**Cuento Chino**", que en realidad es "contar chinos", "contar fabas", "contar los chinos", "contar chinas" (**Echar china**; contar las veces que uno bebe en la taberna, contar las chinas o contar los chinos correspondientes a las bebidas que cada cliente consumía para cobrarlas, cada chino-a, correspondía a una consumición ). Para el cómputo, en el caso de que no hubiera posibilidad de realizarlo con "chinas-chinos", se efectuaba con **pequeñas habas**, que hacían la vez de **pequeña piedrecita**,  como un "chino", pues antiguamente se solía contar ó realizar votaciones internamente, utilizando pequeñas piedrecitas, es decir, "chinos" ó pequeñas habas.

---

**CÓMO CHINO ADQUIRIÓ EL SENTIDO DE FÁBULA**

En ese desatino del destino, habría que preguntarse entonces, ¿cómo "chino" adquirió el sentido de fábula?.

En el encuentro se cruzaron otras voces de significado similar pero de distinta grafía. Así la expresión utilizada " **Contar fabas**", era lo mismo ó sinónimo de "**Contar chinos**", sin embargo, "Faba", "Haba" de "Faba-e" en latín, también se puede escribir Fabula-ae, Fabulum-i, Fabulu-i. Sin embargo, la voz Fabula-ae, no se suele utilizar para referirse a las "fabas", "habas", sino que se toma  habitualmente por fábula, novela, fabuloso, cuento, pero que en esta ocasión coincide y recoge el mismo valor lingüístico para la pequeña "faba" o haba pequeña, (recuérdese que los chinos o chinas y las habas se utilizaban para contar lo que consumía el cliente).

---

[Diccionario manual de la lengua latina: con la correspondencia castellana](https://books.google.es/books?id=7Xq5j6CTn0cC&pg=PA606&lpg=PA606&dq=Fabulus-i,%20latin,%20una%20haba,%20un%20grano%20de%20haba&source=bl&ots=lkWQBvCnNG&sig=ACfU3U2dbA2O6gmNxu2TvdPqHUom-624Mw&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii1sfy-c_3AhWKM-wKHZVBCgEQ6AF6BAgwEAM#v=onepage&q=Fabulus-i%2C%20latin%2C%20una%20haba%2C%20un%20grano%20de%20haba&f=false)

pág. 606

- Fabula-ae f. d. (con el significado de), Haba pequeña.
- Fabulus-i m. Una haba, un grano de haba.

### **FABA COMO FÁBULA**

Así, y repitiendo, se recoge para "Faba" lo mismo que para "Fabula", Fabula-ae, Fabulus..., donde "Contar fabas", "habas", se entiende como "Contar Fabulas", manteniendo el significado que para "Faba", las mismas, tenían para Fabula, como son las fabulas, historias y cuentos, las cosas simuladas, la novela fingida, lo fabuloso, la ficción, las piezas teatrales...

---

**CONTAR CHINOS - CONTAR FABAS - CONTAR FÁBULAS**

Este "contar las chinas", "contar chinos", "cuento" los chinos", o simplemente "el cuento de chinos ó chinas", con el sentido de "contar", no de "narrar", se decía cuando era necesario  "contar fabas".

De esta manera, "contar chinos", recogió por un lado los distintos sentidos que ya hemos visto antes y que incorporaba la voz "fabas", en su confusión con la misma lectura de la voz "fabula" cuando  "contar chinos" y "contar fabas" eran sinónimos habituales, acabando este uso por desaparecer como expresiones de una época, mientras, la voz "chino" recogía o retomaba a su vez, su sentido como voz homófona de "Chino", es decir, como nativo o procedente de "China".

---

**"AQUÍ CUENTO UN CHINO" COMO CUENTO. CONTAR X NARRAR**

Por tanto, "contar" como cómputo, cambio ese valor de calculo "contar", por su sentido narrativo, "contar" como "cuento". "Contar un Cuento" como "El cuento de los años", que tan gráfica y gratamente hemos podido comprobar en la acepción 4ª de la RAE expuesta más arriba, en una interpretación donde la imaginación queda abierta.

---

**CONCLUSIÓN**

El tiempo simplemente acabó por transformar la lectura original de ambas palabras, tanto de la voz "Cuento" como la de "Chino", transformándose en algo tan distinto y popular como "Cuento Chino", ya fuera para designar algo fabuloso, una fábula, una novela fingida, una historia, un cuento, una trampa, una fantasía, una ficción, una mentira....

Siento si el desarrollo del propio resumen resultó largo. La búsqueda ha sido larga y la cuestión llevaba casi dos años sin tener una respuesta. Espero que al menos la espera haya merecido la pena y lo expuesto pueda ser adecuadamente considerado, con las limitaciones propias que un guión tiene para su comprensión.

---

Comment: This is a very long answer but you don't specifically locate the origin of this.